# Using glide for setting the image

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

Android beginner here. 
I am trying to use glide (and I have added the libraries already) to add images to my image view.

Looking at other examples, most people seemed to do:
Glide.with(this).load("link").into(myHolder.image);

But this isn't working when I'm using my adapter class.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyHolder> {
Context c;
ArrayList<Model> models;

public MyAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Model> models) {
    this.c = c;
    this.models = models;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.box_listview, null);
    return new MyHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyHolder myHolder, int i) {
    myHolder.name.setText(models.get(i).getName());
    myHolder.type.setText(models.get(i).getType());
    Glide.with(this).load("http://img.pokemondb.net/artwork/pokemonname.jpg").into(myHolder.image);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return models.size();
}
```

}

There is a red line under this. 
What should go in the context?

Comment: Glide.with(c).load("http://img.pokemondb.net/artwork/pokemonname.jpg").into(myHolder.image);

c is context

Comment: Also, if you are a beginner I recommend you to start learning with Kotlin instead of java.

Comment: The context will be `getActivity()` or `getContext()`, because `adapter` don't have it's own context. change it like below, hope it will solve.
`Glide.with(getActivity()).load("http://img.pokemondb.net/artwork/pokemonname.jpg").into(myHolder.image);`

Comment: Kishan is right! When you pass "this" you really want a "Context" object, it can be a activity, fragmentActivity, or a context itself. As you are passing a context to the adapter, just use it.

Comment: You can up vote me too, If I helped anyways.

Comment: So what is the context of this object? Which activity should I call?

Comment: If you're new to Android (not deeply invested in Java), I strongly recommend you switch to Kotlin!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use Glide.with(this) , `this` is the `context`, you cannot simply use it without knowing what to send.

You may use the `holder.image.getContext()` method to use as context.

Also, check that you are using https on your images, because later Google APIS (since PIE) request you to use secure urls, unless you specify otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

```
Glide.with(this).load("http://img.pokemondb.net/artwork/pokemonname.jpg").into(myHolder.image);
```

Change this above code with below code:

```
Glide.with(c).load("http://img.pokemondb.net/artwork/pokemonname.jpg").into(myHolder.image);
```

Also, kindly check your URL, it is showing 404 - Not found Error. So that might be the case as because image is not loading on your imageview.

Comment: Thank you! what does c represent in this case? Is it just a random context..?

Comment: "c" is your `context` variable declaration. :)